# Postgres function parameter is null then replace it with default value

Tags: postgresql, function, if-statement, parameters, null

I have a postgres function

```
 create or replace function start_batch(in start_date date, int end_date date) returns integer 
as $batch$

BEGIN
    
    if(start_date is null or end_date is null) then
           start_date = date_trunc('month',now())-interval '1 month')::date ;
            end_date = date_trunc('month'now())-interval '1 day')::date;
        end if;
    
    
END;
$bach$ language plpgsql;
```

but i get syntax error SQL errir [42704] ERROR: unrecognized exception condition "is null"
is there any other way to check if in parameter date is null and replace it with default date

Comment: This is not proper syntax for a Postgres function at all. See [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). In what client is this being run and against what version of Postgres?

Comment: this is run in dbeaver and postgres version 14.6. let me correct the create function syntax

Comment: There is no `language plsql`in Postgres. Only `language plpgsql`

Comment: looks like there was a typo

Comment: Also `$batch$ ... $bach$` is wrong.  And `int end_date date` is wrong.  And `start_date = date_trunc('month',now())-interval '1 month')::date ; end_date = date_trunc('month'now())-interval '1 day')::date;`  is wrong. If you want an answer you need to provide an example that is correct in syntax.

Comment: And there is no `RETURN;` If you correct all the errors it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many incorrect syntaxes here.

Sample for you, this is working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(start_date date)
 RETURNS date
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    
    if (start_date is null) then 
    start_date = date_trunc('month', now() - interval '1 month')::date;
    end if; 

    return start_date;
    
end ;
$function$
;

select test(null)

-- Result: 
2022-11-01
```